# Fetch translation files from EFS (Amazon Elastic File System) or S3bucket while using HttpBackend in react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, i18next, react-i18next, amazon-efs

I am new to react-i18next and currently, I'm fetching translation files from the public/locales/en/translation.json directory for English, and following the same structure for other languages. Here is the folder structure of my public folder:

[image: Current File Structure]

Now, I am planning to deploy my React application on AWS. I have around 60 different languages, and including all the translation files in the public folder would unnecessarily increase the build size. Is it possible to fetch these translation files from either an EFS (Amazon Elastic File System) or an S3 Bucket?

I'm confused because I'm unsure if accessing the translation files from the S3 Bucket requires an API or if we can simply use the S3 Bucket URL directly.

I would appreciate any help or guidance on this matter. Thank you.